# Alternative to "accessible"

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, technical, synonyms

In the context of a technical manual, engineers use the word "accessible" to indicate that a piece of hardware should have "easy access" for repair, maintenance, and other modifications.

What would you use instead of "accessible" in such contexts (avoiding the lexeme *access*)?

For example:

> The TMGB must be located such that it is *accessible to* telecommunications personnel.

Comment: *Accessibility* uses the lexeme *access*.

Comment: Why? What's wrong with the lexeme _access_?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could consider:

> The TMGB must be located such that it is **[serviceable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/serviceable) by** telecommunications personnel.

An adjective such as *readily*, *conveniently*, or similar might also be appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

> What would you use instead of "accessible" in such contexts (avoiding the lexeme access)?

***I*** wouldn't; I'd use *accessible to telecommunications personnel*. But you could say it needs to be *easily reached by* or *easily approached by* them. Or that *maintenance and servicing needs to be convenient.*

But nothing quite has the easy simplicity of *accessible*, especially in your quoted context of a technical manual where the word is presumably readily understood.

Comment: +1 An easy utilized version could be *within easy reach*.

Answer (score 0):

How about keeping it simple
"The location of the TMBG should be considered carefully as Telecommunications personnel must be able to get to it for maintenance etc".